# TFS 2010 Build Definition to Build One Project in a Solution

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a VS solution that contains multiple projects and I'm trying to create a build definition to build only one of them.

My project structure in TFS is like this:

```
    $myproject/Dev                            --- myproject.sln file is here
    $myproject/Dev/Src/category/item/project1 --- project I want to build
    $myproject/Dev/Src/web/item/project2      --- project2
    $myproject/Dev/Src/service/item/project3  --- project3

project1 has a project reference set to project2
```

Then I set up my build definition like this:

```
   1. In the Workspace tab

    Status   Source Control Folder                        Build Agent Folder
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Active   $/myproject/Dev/Src/category/item/project1   $(SourceDir)\Dev\Src\category\item\project1
```

In the Process tab, Items to Build | Projects to Build, I select only project1 to build. When I build I get an error:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1200): The referenced project '..\..\..\web\item\project2.csproj' does not exist.
```

If I set the Source Control Folder to $/myproject/Dev and Build Agent Folder to $(SourceDir)\Dev then everything is fine but I only want to kick off the build when something is checked into project1 folder, not everything under $/myproject/Dev.

Comment: Does project1 depend on other projects? It looks like it depends on project2. Try to check your project dependencies.

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to build just Project 1 and not it's referenced projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If project1 reference project2 (as you stated), how do you expect project1 to compile **without** project2 being previously compiled ?

If you only want to compile project1 then you need an assembly reference and not a project reference to project2.

But don't bother, in your build definition build project1 **and** its dependencies, it's simple and efficient.